# can't stop web.config inheritance

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, configuration, endpoint

I created an application inside a website in IIS.

my application is there to host a WCF service endpoint running .Net 4.0 code (the website it is created in, is running .Net 2.0)

when i load this service endpoint, i get an error that models and handlers are missing (because root website has them defined in web.config).

i tried wrapping my **system.web** as well as **system.serviceModel** in the following directive:

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
    ...
  </location>
```

but the handlers and modules continue to try to load.

next, i tried clearing out modules and handlers.

```
<httpModules>
  <clear />
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <clear />
</httpHandlers>
```

this resulted in following error:

> No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

next i tried to manually add only the necessary handler for the .svc

```
     <add 
       verb="*"
       path="*.svc"
       type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

this resulted in:

> Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

in IIS, my application is set to .Net 4.0. I did not see a way to specify the framework on application pool directly (it only has Recycling,Performance,Health,Identity tabs).

all i need to do, is add this virtual dir/application running .net 4.0 inside a 2.0 website, and host a WCF endpoint.

my 4.0 application is running under separate application pool.

adding entire web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" />
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <httpModules>
        <clear />
      </httpModules>
      <httpHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add verb="*" path="*.svc"
          type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <!--<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="extAcctCustMapBinding" maxBufferSize="1000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>-->
      </bindings>

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="DebugBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DebugBehavior" name="MyService">
          <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MyService"
            contract="IMyService" />
        </service>
      </services>

      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have .NET 4.0 running as a nested application inside a .NET 2.0 application.

Comment: well.. at least IIS is not preventing me to create it.. so i am thinking i could make it work ? i mean, if i use a different application pool?

Comment: I see your edit. Are you using Integrated or Classic mode for IIS?

Answer (score 0):

.NET framework version is defined at the application level. You can have a website (www.example.com) running as a .NET 2.0 application, and then set up a virtual directory (i.e. separate application underneath the main site) as a .NET 4.0 application. Application pools cannot share different .NET versions, so you'd need a separate app pool for each application, but this has nothing to do with site configuration.

Having said that, if you have a main site configured as a .NET 2.0 app and a virtual directory configured as a .NET 4.0 app, the .NET 4.0 app cannot inherit the config from the .NET 2.0 app. The config schema is not backward compatible.

Comment: all of this is true above (virtual directory is a application running under different application pool), yet it is inheriting it.

Comment: I think you need to post the entire relevant sections of your parent and child config, and post the exact error. Something seems afoul.

Comment: `inheritInChildApplications="false"` should be specified in the parent config, no the the child config. Also, get rid of the <clear/> statements under modules and handlers. There are a lot of predefined modules in machine.config that you're removing when you do that, setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: i don't want to have the <clears /> actually. that was a last resort after inheritance problem :) .. i was not aware this was a root config setting, i'll try that, thanks

Comment: so.. i can remove specific modules by name <remove name="foo" /> but, when i try to remove handlers this way: <remove verb="*" path="*.ashx" /> , it doesn't work .. meaning, i still see it trying to load on my child application.. any ideas ?

Comment: No idea. I still maintain that a .NET 4.0 app should not be inheriting config from a .NET 2.0 parent app. I think maybe your IIS configuration is messed up. Is it possible for you to try this in a virtual machine on a new server install?

Comment: that's rather extreme. in worst case i can create a new website. but all this is to see if i can avoid having to do that.